# TS7006: Parameter "__"' implicitly has an 'any' type. I'm unable to understand the error & solution below

Tags: typescript, react-native

At fist my code looked like this this

```
  const customerInputHandler = (currentCustomer) => {
    setCustomer(currentCustomer.nativeEvent.text);
  };
```

And after searching the internet I came on a solution and I implemented this code below.
I've being searching around to try and understand this code but unable to.
Could some please explain the error I had above & explain why this solution fixed everything

```
const customerInputHandler = (currentCustomer: {
     nativeEvent: {text: React.SetStateAction<string>};
  }) => {
    setCustomer(currentCustomer.nativeEvent.text);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typescript, everything not given an explicit type (that the compiler can't make some deduction about) is given the type `any`. This isn't necessarily an error -- sometimes things are hard to describe, or can legitimately be `any` (e.g. the result from a `fetch` statement). In these situations, you need to mark the type as *specifically* `any`. Note: I think you can turn off this behavior so implicit `any`s are valid (you should not do this -- otherwise, just use javascript)

As to why the fix worked: 
you gave `currentCustomer` a type. Specifically, it's of type:

```
{
 nativeEvent: {
  text: React.SetStateAction<string>
 }
}
```

So, any value that matches that specific structure can be a parameter to that function. An alternative is to simply make the `any` explicit. That code is approximately:

```
const customerInputHandler = (currentCustomer: any) => {
    setCustomer(currentCustomer.nativeEvent.text);
};
```

though disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this. Again, you'll want to avoid `any` as much as possible, as it quickly spreads throughout the application, rendering a lot of typescript moot.

You may want to see if there's some react native @types package you can include in your project, which may give you a shorthand for the above type.